# pthreads v. SSE weak memory ordering

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, atomic, sse, memory-fences

Do the Linux glibc pthread functions on x86_64 act as fences for weakly-ordered memory accesses? (pthread_mutex_lock/unlock are the exact functions I'm interested in).

SSE2 provides some instructions with weak memory ordering (non-temporal stores such as movntps in particular). If you are using these instructions and want to guarantee that another thread/core sees an ordering, then I understand you need an explicit fence for this, e.g., a sfence instruction.

Normally you do expect the pthread API to act as a fence appropriately.  However, I suspect normal C code on x86 will not generate weakly-ordered memory accesses, so I'm not confident that pthreads needs to act as a fence for weakly-ordered accesses.

Reading through the glibc pthread source code, a mutex is in the end implemented using "lock cmpxchgl", at least on the uncontended path.  So I'm guessing that what I need to know is does that instruction act as a fence for SSE2 weakly-ordered accesses?

Comment: Well no-one answered so I rolled up my sleeves and wrote a test program.  Progress so far:

------
 *  With pthread spinlocks, I can easily demonstrate that they are not fences.
 *  I have failed to produce pthread mutexes not acting as fences.
------

I am not sure if the failure is because the mutexes are fences or because I just got lucky.

My test code is at https://gist.github.com/rcls/c855e3e782253e58e046

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-temporal stores need `sfence` instruction to be ordered properly.

However, the efficient user-level implementation of a simple mutex supposes that it is released by a simple write which does not imply write-buffers flush, in contrast to atomic read-modify-write operations like `lock cmpxchg` which imply full memory fence.

So you have a situation when the `unlock` has no effect of `store-with-release` semantic applied for non-temporal stores. Thus, these SSE stores can be reordered after the unlock and after another thread acquires the mutex.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought only about the lock operation and missed that the ordering semantics of the unlock after the weakly-ordered store is what is critical.

Comment: And re-reading the glibc sourcecode, this is consistent with the results of my testing.
pthread_mutex_unlock, which appears to act as a fence, uses a locked instruction (via lowlevellock).
pthread_spin_unlock uses a normal store.
[Although the other difference is that pthread_spin_unlock is faster - presumably any sufficiently slow operations would in practice act a fence here, even though the architectural description does not guarentee it.]